# ¿Como utilizar xpath como selector en Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

Necesito seleccionar un `div`, en donde no puedo utilizar la clase, por que el nombre de la clase se utiliza en varios `div` mas.

La forma más rápida para llegar es por medio de `xpath`, pero al tratar de utilizarlo me devuelve error, desconozco si se puede utilizar en realidad y cuál es la forma correcta.

```
div[@class='mochaOverlay'])[2]

jQuery('(//div[@class="mochaOverlay"])[2]').css({'width':'364px','height':'281px'});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si no me equivoco, actualmente es necesario utilizar [un plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/xpath/) ¿Te interesa una respuesta con este enfoque?

Comment: si estimado me interesa, no tengo problema en tener que ver un plugin para poder realizarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error lo obtienes debido a que `jQuery` no soporta expresiones `xpath` como [`selector`](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

### Opción 1:

Puedes usar [este plugin](https://github.com/ilinsky/jquery-xpath) para obtener la funcionalidad.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).xpath('(//div[@class="mochaOverlay"])[2]').css({'width':'364px','height':'281px'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-xpath@0.3.1/jquery.xpath.js"></script>

<div class="mochaOverlay">Ejemplo 1</div>
<div class="mochaOverlay">Ejemplo 2</div>
<div class="mochaOverlay">Ejemplo 3</div>
```

---

### Opción 2:

Puedes transformar la expresión `xpath` a un selector `CSS`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$('div.mochaOverlay:nth-of-type(2)').css({'width':'364px','height':'281px'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mochaOverlay">Ejemplo 1</div>
<div class="mochaOverlay">Ejemplo 2</div>
<div class="mochaOverlay">Ejemplo 3</div>
```